# Finding different user_ids with the same session_ids in R

Tags: r

I have a data set containing, among others, these two variables:

```
user_id <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 3)
session_id <- c("a", "a", "b", "c", "d", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "e", "f", "g", "h", "d")
```

Here's my problem: a user_id can take different values of session_id, but a particular session_id, even if it's repeated, can only belong to one user_id. For example, user_id 1 can have many session_ids like a, b, and c, but I want to know if these same session_ids (a, b, c) also appear for other user_ids that are not 1. I would really appreciate any advice on how to do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or by `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
dt = data.table(user_id, session_id)
ans = unique(dt)[, .(user_id=user_id[.N > 1]), by=session_id]
#    session_id user_id
# 1:          a       1
# 2:          a       4
# 3:          b       1
# 4:          b       2
```

We first compute `unique(dt)` which remove identical `user_id, session_id` combinations, and then we group by `session_id`, and for each group, we return `user_id` iff the number of observations in that group are > 1. This is done by making use of `.N` a special variable that holds the number of observations for each group.

If instead you just wanted the `session_id` that has more than one `user_id`, then, you could just do:

```
unique(dt)[, .(N=.N > 1L), by=session_id][(N), session_id]
# [1] "a" "b"
```

Here, after computing the `unique(dt)`, we ask if the number of observations are > one, for each group, and that returns a column `N` which is TRUE/FALSE. Then we just return the `session_id` for all `TRUE` values.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `tapply` for example. You group your user's id by session , and for each id group you check if it contains more than one user id.

```
res <- 
tapply(user_id,session_id,
       function(x)if(length(unique(x))>1)unique(x) else NA)
## remove missing values
res[!is.na(res)]

$a
[1] 1 4

$b
[1] 1 2
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible `dplyr` approach:

```
library(dplyr)

data.frame(user_id, session_id) %>%
  group_by(session_id) %>%
  distinct(user_id) %>%
  filter(n() > 1) %>%
  arrange(session_id)

## Source: local data frame [4 x 2]
## Groups: session_id
## 
##   user_id session_id
## 1       1          a
## 2       4          a
## 3       1          b
## 4       2          b
```

Answer (score 0):

Can use graphical approach:

```
plot(table(user_id, session_id), col=1:10)
```

[image]

This is based on following output of table command:

```
> table(user_id, session_id)
       session_id
user_id a b c d e f g h
      1 3 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
      2 0 2 2 0 0 0 0 0
      3 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0
      4 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
      5 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
      6 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
      7 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
```

Only 'a' and 'b' have more than one user_id associated with them.